# PHP SoapClient call response missing parts of answer

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I have a problem with the script below. It just doesn't want to post back any response.

The script:

```
    <?php

    require_once('nusoap.php');
    $c = new soapclient('http://hidden.com/api/soap_affiliate.php?wsdl');

    $result = $c->__call('optionalInfo', array('client'=> 'hidden','add_code' => 'hidden','password'=> 'hidden' , 
'start_date' => '2011-03-15','end_date' => '2011-03-24' , 'program_id' => '000' , 'opt_info' => 'x' ));

    echo $result; 

    ?>
```

What gets returned is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<item>
</item>
```

it should return some details from my clients although it doesn't even show empty fields.

What it should look like with some more details is this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<item> 
     <dailystats> 
         <date>2011-03-18</date> 
         <impressions>17</impressions> 
         <clicks>1</clicks> 
         <leads>1</leads> 
         <num_sales>0</num_sales> 
         <sales> 0.00</sales> 
         <sub_sales> 0.00</sub_sales>  
         <commission> 1.10</commission> 
         <click_thru_ratio>5.88%</click_thru_ratio> 
</dailystats> 
</item>
```

I have tried anything I can (for how much I know soap ) but it wont return anything else.
So can someone help me out with this script?

The needed webservice is below,

```
- <message name="optionalInfoRequest">
  <part name="client" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <part name="add_code" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <part name="password" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <part name="start_date" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <part name="end_date" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <part name="program_id" type="xsd:int" /> 
  <part name="opt_info" type="xsd:string" /> 
  </message>
- <message name="optionalInfoResponse">
  <part name="return" type="xsd:string" /> 
  </message>
```

the whole WSDL can be found here [WSDL service](http://network.thinkaction.com/api/soap_affiliate.php?wsdl)

**EDIT:**

thanks wrikken, It pushed me in the right direction. I have edited the script a little bit: Now there is an "opt_info" tag. Here I have to put e-mail addresses and a date so that it returns them too. Can anybody help me do this?

Comment: Most likely a logical / data error (for instance, an invalid program_id, so data is missing), as there seems to be no problem with the code. Have you tried the normal built-in soap client just to be sure?

Comment: @wrikken I have edited the post. It does work indeed only it doesn't retrieve anything because I am not sending anything, can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Do you require the use of nusoap? PHP now has it's own SOAP handling which is much easier to understand (At least for me as a traditional PHP programmer, I found nusoap a bit confusing). If you are just starting to learn SOAP and you have a PHP version that supports it natively, with --enable libxml (might need to be recompiled with soap support) it might be a good idea to learn PHP's method.

Here is an example client script that sends a request and *should* receive a response, it also prints out the errors in a "var dump":

```
        <?php
        try {
            $sClient = new SoapClient("http://URL-TO-WSDL");
            $response = $sClient->doFunctionName($REQUEST);
//doFunctionName should represent the name of the "message" element
//and $REQUEST is what you are sending to the server for that same message element
            print_r($response);
        } catch(SoapFault $error) {
            var_dump($error);
        } ?>
```

Hope this is useful. BTW: you can check if your php has soap support using phpinfo();, search for "soap" it should read --enable-soap